# Setting css styling for a specific mat table in angular

Tags: css, angular-material

I have multiple angular material tables and I need to use css over one of the tables.

```
.mat-table-sticky:first-child {
border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

I want to use the above css styling. How to implement this css for a specific table?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your specific table inside a div and assign a class to it like this -

```
<div class="specific-table-name">
    <mat-table>...</mat-table>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS, you can give your specific style using this class -

```
.specific-table-name .mat-table-sticky:first-child {
     border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```